# Reference column id is coming up as null while joining

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am trying to build one to many relationship.

**Survey Response details**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_response_details")
public class SurveyResponseDetail {
    protected Long id;
    private SurveyResponseModel surveyResponseModel;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="response_id")
    public SurveyResponseModel getSurveyResponseModel() {
        return surveyResponseModel;
    }

    // setter of id and surveyResponseModel
}
```

**Survey response**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "survey_response")
public class SurveyResponseModel{
        protected Long id;
        private List<SurveyResponseDetail> surveyResponseDetails;

        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,     mappedBy = "surveyResponseModel")
    public List<SurveyResponseDetail> getSurveyResponseDetails() {
        return surveyResponseDetails;
    }

        // setter of id and surveyResponseDetails
}
```

**Main class**

```
if(!surveyResponseDetailList.isEmpty())
                    surveyResponseModel.setSurveyResponseDetails(surveyResponseDetailList);

session.save(surveyResponseModel);
```

But when I am trying to save it, while saving surveyResponseDetail
it is showing error that response_id cannot be null, as I have kept it to be not null. Please help.

Comment: just try this code in the if condition -> if (!surveyResponseDetailList.isEmpty() | (surveyResponseDetailList != null))
and tell me, whether it worked or not?

Comment: please paste the complete stacktrace of your error